# Collection Navigation Properties using Inheritance (Table Per Type )

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, navigation-properties

Using Entity Framework: Code First, I am trying to define an collection navigation property using a navigation property of a base class.

Object structure:

```
public class Content
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ModerationStatuses ModerationStatus { get; set; }
    public ContentItemTypes ContentType { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}

public class Image : Content
{
    public Image()
        : base()
    {
        ContentType = ContentItemTypes.Image;
    }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Context OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
    .Map(i => i.ToTable("Content"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
    .Map(i => i.ToTable("Images"));
```

When the database is generated, it creates a User_UserID foreign key constraint into the Images table instead of using Author_UserID in the Content table.

How can I get it to recognize Content..Author_UserID field as the foreign key for the `ICollection<Image>` navigation property?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You either need to move the `Author` property from the `Content` into the `Image` class **or** make the collection in `User` of type `ICollection<Content> Contents`. A navigation property must always be **declared** in the entity class the inverse navigation property is refering to. It cannot be inherited from a base entity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible... You just need to add a navigation property to your Content class so that you then have a reference to map to.

Here's the thorough [walkthrough](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx).